# sizeof(abcde) in C when abcde is both a type and a pointer

Tags: c, language-lawyer, typedef, sizeof

Let me preface this by acknowledging that it's easy enough to avoid this situation by naming types and variables in a way that they don't overlap.

Nevertheless, I'm curious what would happen in the following case:

```
typedef char jimmypage;

jimmypage *jimmypage;
```

Would `sizeof(jimmypage)` be equivalent to `sizeof(char)` or `sizeof(char *)`?

Comment: I believe it wouldn't actually compile, did you not just try it?

Comment: I think it would take sizeof(char*)

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/LU3HBw)

Comment: My compiler (gcc 6.3.0)  error-ed with  "jimmypage' redeclared as different kind of symbol" for `jimmypage *jimmypage;`  What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: It's also easy to avoid the confusion by omitting the parentheses. After all, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. If the `typedef char jimmypage;` was in a surrounding block, and `jimmypage *jimmypage;` in an inner block, the code compiles. Then `sizeof jimmypage` always refers to the size of the pointer type (`char *`); and `sizeof *jimmypage` always refers to the size of the pointed to type (`char`). This last one has the benefit that it'll always yield the correct size. If you change the variable declaration to `long *jimmypage;`, then `sizeof *jimmypage == sizeof long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's [make it work](http://ideone.com/E3srLY):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char synonym;

int main(void) {

  synonym *synonym;
  printf("sizeof (synonym) = %ld\n", (long) sizeof (synonym));
  return 0;
}
```

The declaration

```
synonym *synonym;
```

declares a variable with the name `synonym` of type pointer to type `synonym` (equivalent to `char`) declared in the surrounding block. This declaration *shadows* the identifier `synonym` declared in the surrounding block, with the effect that from this point forward to the end of the current block, the identifier `synonym` will refer to the variable and not the type; that is, in the rest of the block the type name `synonym` can no longer be used, because `synonym` is a variable.

Supplementary note:

The declaration is legal because the type was declared in a surrounding block. Trying to declare the variable at the same level as the type

```
typedef char synonym;
synonym *synonym;          // Syntax error: identifier redeclared
```

is a syntax error because the identifier `synonym` would be redeclared with a different meaning.

Extra supplementary note:

Two words are *synonyms* if they have the same meaning. Two words with the same form but different meanings are [*homonyms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym).

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking about the size of a pointer compared to a value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char synonym;

int main()
{
    synonym* ptr;
    synonym  val;

    printf("ptr: %d\n", sizeof(ptr));
    printf("val: %d\n", sizeof(val));

    return 0;
}
```

Gives me:

```
ptr: 8
val: 1
```

If you're asking about which thing (the type or the variable) the compiler will use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char synonym;

int main()
{
    synonym* synonym;

    printf("synonym: %d\n", sizeof(synonym));

    return 0;
}
```

Gives me:

```
synonym: 8
```

So the local identifier `main -> synonym` takes precedence over the global `typedef char synonym`.

Comment: The question is about using a variable whose name is the same as a `typedef`. Your example has nothing like that.

Comment: @Barmar Ah - I didn't realise that. I've amended my answer.

Comment: You can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: @Barmar Fixed again, sorry!

Comment: Please use `"%zu"` and not `"%d"` to print `sizeof` expressions.

Comment: @aschepler From what I can tell `%zu` is a C++11 feature, is it in C99 or C11?

Comment: @Dai I think it's actually originally a C99 feature :)

Comment: The old school portable method of printing `sizeof(...)` is `printf("synonym: %lu\n", (unsigned long) sizeof(synonym));`  Works also for most modern implementations too.